# How to show PDF file using Spring Web application

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I wish to show this file on page but this code make a direct download

`<a th:href="@{/pdf/Manjaro-User-Guide.pdf}">Show Pdf file</a>`

I'm using Spring-Thymeleaf

Thanks!

Comment: I think whether a PDF downloads or opens in the browser depends on the browser settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution by commenting the line below

```
//response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"demo.pdf\"");
```

Here is the code example:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/pdf")
    public void showPDF(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        //response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"demo.pdf\"");
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(rootLocation + "/Manjaro-User-Guide.pdf"));
        int nRead;
        while ((nRead = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
            response.getWriter().write(nRead);
        }
    }
```

[Source](https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-download-file-example/)

Thanks!